# Why the textfield hasn't accept the characters?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I've designed a UItableView and for that I've done cell customisation with a textfield, during the execution of this program I getting blank textfield. I've tried cellname.textfieldname.enable=NO, but still it display blank value?

Here is my code:

```
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifiers=@"Cell";
    RemovedEquip *eqp = [tblArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomcelliPad *cell = (CustomcelliPad *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifiers];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *array=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomcelliPad" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=(CustomcelliPad *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.removedequipment_txt.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bordeaux Medium" size:13.0];
    cell.removedequipment_txt.text=[[tblArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RemovedEquipmentDescription"];//Here I'm getting the text from an array.
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you verified that `[[tblArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RemovedEquipmentDescription"];` actually returns the expected value?

Comment: YES. Also I've verified by replacing some default string (ex. @"Hello World", but it doesn't display the value.

Comment: what does po cell.removedequipment_txt return ? if nil the property is not created / binded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `NSLog` and see the value which you are getting in the console for

```
[[tblArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RemovedEquipmentDescription"];
```

If the value is present then it should show, in case not then check if your array gets populated before the table view is rendered, In case you are building up your array after the view has been loaded then you need to reload your table view data. Just put this line after your array builds up -

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

It should work fine.

Comment: did you get the data in NSlog

Comment: Can you add a bit more code as to when and how you Initialize your array